# Divide in pandas based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I would like to calculate `time_spent_ratio`(time spent phone vs. tablet for a given `customer_id` and given 
`month` , where I divide `time_spent` on phone with `time_spent` on tablet.

Main Table

```
date_month.  customer_id. device_name  time_spent 

01-01-19     2             phone       140
01-01-19     2             tablet      232
01-02-19     2             phone       159
01-02-19     2             tablet      210
01-03-19     2             phone       193
01-03-19     2             tablet      190
```

Output table

```
date_month  customer_id   time_spent_ratio
01-01-19    2             0.603
01-02-19    2             0.757
01-03-19    2             1.0157
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a pivot table first before creating the ratio column.
Considering your main DataFrame is df -

```
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['date_month','customer_id'], columns='device_name', values='time_spent') #Pivoting on required columns(date and customer_id)
df_flattened = pd.DataFrame(df_pivot.to_records()) #Flatten the pivot table to get a datafrmae
df_flattened['time_spent_ratio'] = df_flattened['phone']/df_flattened['tablet'] #Creating the ratio column
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to set all the other columns, except `time_spent`, as the index, then divide rows for phone by rows for tablet.

```
#set all other columns except time_spent as index
res = df.set_index(["device_name","date_month.","customer_id."])

#divide phone rows by tablet rows
res.loc['phone'].div(res.loc['tablet'])


                            time_spent
date_month. customer_id.    
01-01-19       2            0.603448
01-02-19       2            0.757143
01-03-19       2            1.015789
```

Comment: You could assign the last line to `res` and later reset indexes `res = res.reset_index(['date_month.', 'customer_id.'])`

Comment: Thanks mate. your suggestion also gets the one-liner as well :)